# Node.js Stream picture via Filestream to gm

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a node server and will stream png-Files. The images are encrypted.
With createReadStream i'm able to decrypt the file. Then i will resize the picture with gm (with graphicsmagick) but i do not know how to stream to gm and afterwards back to the client.

All examples i found in web use gm with file input (i need a stream).

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
var gm = require("gm");
var rstream = fs.createReadStream(lPathPicture);  
pRes.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});  

rstream  
    .pipe(aes)  // decrypt file  
   **.pipe(....)   // How to call gm with stream ?**  
    .pipe(pRes)  
    .on('finish', function () {  // finished  
        pRes.end();  
        return;  
    })  
    .on('error', function (err) {  // error  
        .....  
    });
```

Comment: I will try https://github.com/sidorares/exec-stream  (with gm (graphicsmagick)). Something like: 
var execStream = require('exec_stream'); 
var convert = execStream('gm', ['the options']); 
rstream.pipe(aes).pipe(convert).pipe(res);

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
var SpawnStream = require('spawn-stream');  // https://www.npmjs.org/package/spawn-stream
var gm = require("gm");
.
.
var rstream = fs.createReadStream(lPathPicture);   
var lOptions = {};
var args = ["arg1", "arg2"];    
var processPic = SpawnStream('gm', args, lOptions);
pRes.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
rstream
  .pipe(aes)
  .pipe(processPic)
  .pipe(wstream)
  .on('finish', function () { 
    pRes.end();
    return;
    })
  .on('error', function (err) {  // error
    ...
    });
```